# Can I stack elements with overlap using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to position unknown number of elements in a container so that it appears to be stacked when that container is not big enough? I'm trying to do this with only HTML and CSS.

Here's what it looks like if the parent is bigger than the children.

[image]

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish when there are more children occupying the parents (fill color to show stacking order):

[image]

Some things I looked at but had no luck with (maybe I'm missing something or just not that good):

1. CSS counter - only works for content property
2. Nesting the children `div` within each other (like Inception)
3. CSS flexbox - it only wraps or shrinks

Here's kind off what I'm trying to do: http://codepen.io/vickyleong/pen/VaPBYg.
Try to resize the window.

**NOTE**: The children are squares, but stacked with overlap, like cascade

I'm using Sass, but here is my code with just HTML and CSS:

```css
body, * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.card {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  border: 1px solid #F4F4F4;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 1px #DDD;
}

.card-content {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.student-pic-sm {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.round-pic {
  background-color: #AAA;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.batch-list-item .card-title h2 {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
.batch-list-item .card-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
.batch-list-item .student-pic-list {
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}
.batch-list-item .round-pic {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  overflow: visible;
}
.batch-list-item .round-pic .round-pic {
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.batch-list-item .round-pic:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #BBB;
}
.batch-list-item .round-pic:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.batch-list-item .space-filler {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}
.batch-list-item .students-count {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 8rem;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 8rem;
          flex: 0 0 8rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
.batch-list-item .students-count p {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

.student-pic-list {
  position: relative;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div {
  left: 8%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div {
  left: 12%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 16%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 20%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 24%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 28%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 32%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 36%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 40%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 44%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 48%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 52%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 56%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 60%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 64%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 68%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 72%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 76%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 80%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 84%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 88%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 92%;
}
.student-pic-list > div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div {
  left: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="batch-1" class="batch-list-item card">
  <div class="card-title">
    <h2>Pending Batch</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="student-pic-list">
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="round-pic student-pic-sm">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="students-count">
      <p>14 students</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add a `jsfiddle` link? or show us some code! also have a question: did you try `flex-box` ?

Comment: link to codepen is added to the OP

Comment: are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/87skemx9/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

negative margins except on the first-of-type:

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    background: lavender;
}

#container {
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */    
    display: flex;
    outline: 1px solid hotpink;
}

.inner {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;   
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.3s ease; /* Safari */
    transition:  margin-left 0.3s ease;
    border: 2px dashed black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.2);
}

.inner:first-of-type, #container:hover .inner:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0; 
}

#container:hover .inner {
    margin-left: -30px;  
}

img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<div class=inner><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=pic></div>  
<div class=inner><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=pic></div> 
<div class=inner><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=pic></div> 
<div class=inner><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=pic></div> 
<div class=inner><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=pic></div> 
<div class=inner><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=pic></div> 
<div class=inner><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=pic></div> 
<div class=inner><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufh1gnC.png" alt=pic></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't being clear. The second picture suppose to show that the elements are overlapping and stacked.

Comment: if you want them to overlap instead of shrink you can use negative margins example `margin-left: -50px`

Comment: Thanks. You made it much simpler than I thought. This will give me a much-needed breakthrough!

Comment: The earlier flex was my fault I didnt read the question until the end; the question is well explained and complete.

Comment: Just curious, why alt=star (no quotes)?

Comment: @nocturns2 the previous image was [**this**](http://i.imgur.com/p6sVAWS.png) but when i made an update on the answer i did change the image aswell (although the 'alt' was forgotten, thanks for warning)

Comment: You should avoid transitioning `margin` and use a `transform: translate` instead for performance reasons

Comment: @ZachSaucier thanks for your comment, but it don't work in this situation because the next object ignores the transform of the previous one so they don't overlap. I could workaround this situation setting different transform values for them with `:nth-child(n)` but the OP demands an unknown number of elements [**here's a working pen of this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNWVvM?editors=1100)

Comment: _ps: tested with `transform-origin` and `transform-style: preserve-3d;` but the result is the same;_